# Are the tumbleweed criteria different between members of the trilogy?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, tumbleweed-badge

Are the maximum number of views allowed for tumbleweed-qualifying questions different between different members of the Stack Overflow trilogy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question in question is "[Mac equivalent of FinePrint’s ability to merge print jobs](https://superuser.com/questions/17466/mac-equivalent-of-fineprints-ability-to-merge-print-jobs)", then it looks like the upvote on the question, as well as being marked a favourite, discounts it from becoming a Tumbleweed.

Now what you have to do is track down that person who clicked on the star and harangue them for denying you [a Tumbleweed badge](https://superuser.com/badges/38/tumbleweed).

Comment: I should've done this to that dude who answered my probable tumbleweed-worthy question.

Comment: The tumbleweed criteria don't mention marking as favorite or upvotes.

Comment: was right: the [upvote killed it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59145/tumbleweed-criteria-not-documented-properly).

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know definitively, I'm guessing not. Why?

Comment: There's a question I asked on superuser that hasn't yet earned tumbleweed, even though I think it has had fewer views than one that earned tumbleweed in stackoverflow. Also, they don't specify how many views disqualifies you for tumbleweed, and I assume they're hiding that info for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't imagine that the criteria are any different. Are you sure that the question in question has gone on for the correct amount time?

Comment: It's 15 days old (17 if you count from Horses' birthday), and it should be for one week.