# Tumbleweed criteria not documented properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tumbleweed-badge

The tumbleweed criteria seems to include upvotes or downvotes, but this isn't documented in the description.

Examples where upvotes or downvotes apparently disqualified tumbleweed include [Are the tumbleweed criteria different between members of the trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/are-the-tumbleweed-criteria-different-between-members-of-the-trilogy/14874#14874), [Tumbleweed badge for an upvoted (not-answered) question ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/tumbleweed-badge-for-an-upvoted-not-answered-question) and [Slow motion tumbleweed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59086/slow-motion-tumbleweed/59143#59143), where a tumbleweed was awarded 7 months after the question was asked when downvotes were accidentally deleted, and revoked when the downvotes were restored.

The current documentation for tumbleweed says `Asked a question with no answers, no comments, and low views for a week.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changed to

> Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The irony quotient of meta is slightly decreased.

Comment: Referring to answers and comments in linked questions: Does favouriting prevent a tumbleweed? If not, all is clear. Otherwise the description should be updated again.

Comment: `low views`, is 10 low? is 100 low? is 1000 low?

Comment: @Mr.Pallazzo I've just earned the "Nice question" tag for this. How non self demonstrating.

Comment: yeah, what @EnricoPallazzo said