# Tumbleweed text on Programmers.SE is out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tumbleweed-badge

According to [Tumbleweed criteria not documented properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59145/tumbleweed-criteria-not-documented-properly/61123#61123), the text of the Tumbleweed badge should read:

> Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

And in fact, the text is correct on all the Trilogy sites and a random sample of the Stack Exchange beta sites. But on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges) and its [meta-discussion site](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/badges), the Tumbleweed badge has the old text:

> Asked a question with no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

Comment: Just to supplement this - as of right now, all of the graduated SE 2.0 sites have the correct description *except* for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/badges/21/tumbleweed) and [CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/badges/21/tumbleweed). For Beta sites, the only ones that *do* have the correct description are DIY, GIS, Money, UI, and Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All descriptions have been updated for the Tumbleweed badge network wide.