# Tumbleweed badge - do close votes alter the outcome?

Tags: support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

[Projector control - RS232 / USB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801593/projector-control-rs232-usb)

The above question has been open for well over a week now, it's got no comments, no answers and only 23 views or so (judging by Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32376/tumbleweed-how-many-views-is-low) that shouldn't be the factor anyway!)

It does have one close vote though, that's the only thing I can think of?

All the other questions about this seem to have been resolved when the user already had the tumbleweed badge - I however don't!

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this badge calculation only runs every so often.  Perhaps you need to wait for a few more days before it will show up?

Comment: The question received an upvote. It looks to me like that vote was cast on the day the question was asked. Perhaps I'm reading [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6801593/timeline) incorrectly?

Comment: @M. Tibbits I did wonder this, but I would've thought it'd be every couple of days at least? I may well be mistaken though.

Comment: [Note the description here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59145/tumbleweed-criteria-not-documented-properly)

Comment: @berry - Posting here just risks getting more views. And the odd upvote...

Comment: Ah, sorry it's me - I didn't read the description properly and missed the vote bits out! False alarm (as per usual I'd guess!) I'd query why the vote takes out the badge though? There's still no feedback to the question which can be just as annoying :)

Comment: @Bo I don't hugely care about the badge, I was more curious as to why it wasn't awarded - as for views Jeff said that's almost never the limiting factor anyway, so...:)

Comment: I am still curious whether close votes matter for the badge, though. I'd think that the devs would have assumed that any post receiving a close vote would have also gotten at least a downvote or a comment.

Comment: Perhaps, though (as you've probably seen) that isn't the case with the above question. Personally I think especially if there's no comments there already a close vote should be forced to leave a comment, but that's another matter entirely!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question has one upvote.  This disqualifies it from the Tumbleweed badge.  Sorry!